# Couting a Mysql Table

Tags: mysql

I have two Mysql tables which are:
1 - Main table (_benefits) which consists of benefitCode, benefitName and
2 - Second table which consists of clientID, benefitCode1, benefitCode2, etc.

what I need is that when I do a SELECT * FROM _benefits
I get a COUNT of all clients receiving the corresponding benefitCode

a small example would be:

**Main Table**

`Benefit Code   Benefit Name
 6MBO           6 Monthly Bonus
 AP             Age Pension`

**Beneficiaries Table**

```
clientID    6MBO  AP
123M        1     0
456M        1     1
```

Required Output Select statement should give

```
Benefit Code   Benefit Name          Total    
6MBO           6 Monthly Bonus         2
AP             Age Pension             1
```

Thank you for your assistance

Comment: You should redesign your beneficiaries table and have clientid and benefit code fields only. In this case you would only need a simple join. With your current table structure, you need to unpivot your beneficiaries table because it is a pivot table.

Comment: if I do as you mentioned above I will be having an amount of 175,000 rows x the number of benefits so that was my aim in having the benefits as fields and the ID card (to reduce the number of records).

Comment: That 's not such a high number as you would think!